# Back arrow missing from ActionBar on release build but not debug build

Tags: android, android-layout, proguard, android-proguard, android-jetpack

When I move from the debug build of my Android app to the release build, the back navigation arrow in the ActionBar gets replaced by the hamburger (for want of a better name), which is not what I want.

Here is the debug build, with the back arrow as it should be.

[image]

And here is the release build, with the hamburger.

[image]

It's the default back arrow that appears when the user navigates to a fragment using Jetpack Navigation Component, in an AppBarLayout that looks like this:

```
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

When I turn minification off in the release version, the back arrow reappears. So it's something to do with minification.

But what do I tell ProGuard to keep?  I tried all this but none of it helped:

```
-keep class androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar{}
-keep class androidx.navigation.NavController{}
-keep class androidx.navigation.Navigation{}
-keep class androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration{}
-keep class androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp.** {*;}
-keep class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment{}
-keep class com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout{}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and found it in [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119886481). Someone had a solution there :

```
-keep class androidx.appcompat.graphics.drawable.DrawerArrowDrawable { *; }
```

Apparently, the back arrow drawable (DrawerArrowDrawable) is obfuscated by Proguard by default. This solved the problem for me and I don't have any of your other Proguard rules.

And you should also replace `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` with `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` (although it's not related to your question)

Comment: This is why I love stackoverflow. Problem solved instantly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you're using:

- androidx navigation library 2.2.0
- disabled androidx jetifier

you'll encounter this problem because the proguard rule still referenced the Support library version.

It is fixed in Navigation 2.2.1 and later(see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147610424)

Comment: I am using Navigation 2.3.0-alpha06 and the issue still exists.

Comment: @HimanshuMalik just confirmed it's fixed in [2.3.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.3.0), also the animation appears to be smoother.